# SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase() method is crashing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyAccountsDB.db";

    public static final String TABLE_Accounts = "Accounts";

    public static final String COLUMN_AccountID= "AccountID";
    public static final String COLUMN_WebSite= "WebSite";
    public static final String COLUMN_Email= "Email";
    public static final String COLUMN_UserName = "UserName";
    public static final String COLUMN_Password= "Password";


    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String INT_TYPE = " INTEGER";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_Accounts =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Accounts +
                    " (" +
                    COLUMN_AccountID + INT_TYPE +" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL"+ COMMA_SEP +
                    COLUMN_WebSite + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    COLUMN_Email + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    COLUMN_UserName + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    COLUMN_Password+ TEXT_TYPE + ")";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_Accounts);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Accounts);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void CreateAccount(Account acc)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        String insertAccount = "Insert into Accounts (WebSite,Email,UserName,Password) values" +
        "('" + acc.getWebSite() + "','" + acc.geteMail() + "','" + acc.getUserName() + "','" + acc.getPassWord() + "')";
        db.execSQL(insertAccount);
    }

    public ArrayList<Account> getAllAccounts()
    {
        String query = "SELECT AccountID , WebSite FROM Accounts";
        ArrayList<Account> Accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();//when its called here no problem and load all the accounts the way i want
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c != null)
        {
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.setAccountID(c.getInt(0));
                acc.setWebSite(c.getString(1));
                Accounts.add(acc);
            }
        }
        return Accounts;
    }
    public Account getAccountByID(int id)
    {
        Account acc  = new Account();
        String query = "SELECT WebSite , eMail , UserName , Password from Accounts where AccountID = " + id;
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();//but when i call it here following exception thrown 
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c != null)
        {
            while (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                acc.setAccountID(c.getInt(0));
                acc.setWebSite(c.getString(1));
                acc.seteMail(c.getString(2));
                acc.setUserName(c.getString(3));
                acc.setPassWord(c.getString(4));
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }
```

---

```
NullPointerException :
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
```

I have another application with the same methods and functions syntax and it's working with no problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What are you putting the columns in the strings instead of using `COLUMN_AccountID`, for example? And do you really need to store the password in a Java `Account` object?

Comment: thank you...but the same calling syntax for getReadableDatabase() is working well from the getAllAccounts method

Comment: am using int datatype for the auto increment

Comment: It shouldn't be working, though, according to that error. The `Context` is null

Comment: @cricket_007 i've told you...its working well and functional in `getAllAccounts` method !!

Comment: Please show where you call that method with an [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all...i've found the answer....i was calling the
`getAccountById` method from a fragment...so i must re-pass the
 Context again to it

```
UpdateAccountFragment a = new UpdateAccountFragment(accountID,getActivity());
```

and the constructor of the `UpdateAccountFragment` look like

```
 public UpdateAccountFragment (int accountID , Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.accountID = accountID;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass a Context to any Fragment. You can simply use `getActivity()` in the second Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create the database helper differently.

For example,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DatabaseHelper db; // Don't initialize here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        ...
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this); // Do it here
    }
}
```

And that should fix the current error if you use the same `db` variable throughout the activity, but you still have other issues in the SQL queries that don't match your table definition.

You also don't want to use `while (c.moveToFirst())` unless you want that loop to never end.

```
public Account getAccountByID(int id)
{
    Account acc  = new Account();
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_Accounts, 
            { COLUMN_WebSite , COLUMN_Email , COLUMN_UserName , COLUMN_Password }, 
            COLUMN_AccountID + "=?", 
            { String.valueOf(id) }, 
            null, null, null, null);
        );    

    try {
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
        {
            acc.setAccountID(id);
            acc.setWebSite(c.getString(0));
            acc.seteMail(c.getString(1));
            acc.setUserName(c.getString(2));
            acc.setPassWord(c.getString(3));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (c != null) c.close();
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your code...but i've solved it :)....it was when calling a fragment from another fragment you must pass the activity's context to it by the`getActivity()'

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score -1):

**The problem is a in your Query:**

```
String query = "SELECT WebSite , eMail , UserName , Password from Accounts where AccountID = " + id;
```

You have used `eMail` instead of `Email`. There is no `column` in your `Accounts` table named `eMail`. Also change `from` to `FROM` and `where` clause to `WHERE`.

**Change your `Query` as below:**

```
String query = "SELECT WebSite , Email , UserName , Password FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = " + id;
```

**#** Create `instance` of `DatabaseHelper` from your `Activity` or `Fragment` like below:

**From Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this); // Context is this

        ...............
        ....................
    }

}
```

**From Fragment:**

```
public class UpdateAccountFragment extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); // Context is getActivity()

        ...............
        ....................
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Why are you suggesting SQL injection?

Comment: thank you again...still not working...my problem is not in SQL queries at all

Comment: what do you mean cricket_007 ?? is there another way to fetch data from sqlite database ?

Comment: @HaniMounla This is only one of the many problems you have. The Context used in `new DatabaseHelper()` is not correct, but you need to update your question with that code

Comment: @FerdousAhamed How does `this.getReadableDatabase();` change anything?

Comment: thank you again @FerdousAhamed but still no working :(